# Why the behaviour of $emit with asnyc in vue2 is not same with the normal function?

Tags: vuejs2, emit

For easy to reproduce, I use openpen to demo it.

```
function foo() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
    });
}

Vue.component('child', {
    template: '<div @click="handleClick">Click</div>',
  
    methods: {
        async handleClick() {
            console.log(1);
            const a = await this.$emit('abc');
            console.log(2);
        }
    }
});

//Root Instance
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '<child @abc="handleAbc" />',
    data: {},
    methods: {
        async handleAbc() {
            console.log(3);
            await foo();
            console.log(4);
        }
    }
})
```

If I click the div, the result is 1 3 2 4.

```
function foo() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
    });
}

async function foo1() {
    console.log(3);
    await foo();`abc`
    console.log(4);
}

async function foo2() {
    console.log(1);
    await foo1();
    console.log(2);
}
foo2();
```

If I use the normal function, the result is 1 3 4 2.

Somebody can explain the reason why the result is not same.

Answer (score 0):

`$emit` does not return a Promise, putting an `await` ahead of it means to continue when all queued-up operations are handled.

Functionally, it is the same as this (numbers are in print order):

```js
async function action(){
  console.log(1)
  await emit() // <--- run emit and put in queue
  console.log(5)
}

function emit(){
  console.log(2)
  handler() // <--- regular function call, continues when handler() returns
  console.log(4)
}

async function handler(){
  console.log(3)
  await new Promise(setTimeout) // <--- return Promise, put in queue
  console.log(6)
}

action()
```

Note that queued items are handled in order, so `action()` will continue before `handler()`.

---

In your second example, the awaited function does return a Promise, execution will continue when the Promise resolves. The order becomes apparent when you replace `async/await` with `.then()` (numbers in print order):

```js
function action(){
  console.log(1)
  return handler().then(() => {
    console.log(4)
  })
}

function handler(){
  console.log(2)
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    console.log(3)
  })
}

action()
```